Another + compound subject + plural or singular verb?
I wanted to understand which of the following two is correct,

Let me know if another day and time works better for you.

or

Let me know if another day and time work better for you.

I found examples of both on the internet, and Grammarly seems to accept both versions.
However, when I was playing around with similar sentences, Grammarly suggested the following two sentences are correct:

A mother and daughter are playing, and another mother and daughter are playing, too.

and

A mother and daughter are playing, and another is playing, too.

My question is, should I use singular or plural verbs with "another + compound subject + verb," and does it matter whether or not the compound subject is present in the sentence?

I suggest that in your first pair of sentences, day and time constitutes a single entity, and that the fact that we conventionally express it with a construction of the form A and B is irrelevant. In the same way, one might express a single price in terms of dollars and cents. Consider also that just as we might say, “A week is a long time,” we would also say “One hundred sixty-eight hours is a long time.” We would not say *”One hundred sixty-eight hours are a long time.” By contrast, the mother and daughter are being thought of as individuals.

I'm going to guess that Grammarly does not approve of "... and another mother and daughter is playing." The only way your final example can be valid is if the meaning is changed, and "another" is understood to mean "another [person]."

@AndyBonner  Thank you for your comment. Just to clarify, are you suggesting that Grammarly accepts my final sentence, 'A mother and daughter are playing, and another is playing, too,' because it doesn't recognize that 'another' refers to another mother and daughter, and therefore the correct form should be plural?"

Yes. I'll go ahead and make a full answer...

One thing is clear: If we really have a compound subject, then the verb should be plural. The complicating thing is that sometimes two nouns with "and" in the middle are not actually a compound subject, but a single noun phrase.


Phineas and Ferb is a good show. (There are two characters, but the words are being used together as one TV show title.)\
Research and Development has a report for us. (The phrase "research and development" is often used as a unit, and stands for "the research and development department" and is treated as a singular.)


When you find "another day and time" being treated as singular, it must be because these two data points are treated as one (after all, Wednesday at 8:00 is a single point in time). As you found, this is reasonable and common enough but treating them as a plural is also (as this ngram confirms).
"Mother and daughter" are harder to treat as a singular. They are not an established phrase like "peanut butter and jelly," and unlike "day and time" they aren't as easily treated as pointing to one single idea. It's hard to imagine any context in which "another mother and daughter is playing" would be the right choice.
"A mother and daughter are playing, and another is playing too" could be a grammatically valid sentence if the meaning is changed, since the antecedent of "another" is unclear. It can often be used to mean simply "another [person]," as in "My true love loves another." But by itself, it defaults to singular: "I've had four beers; pour me another" means another one, not another four.
